# Deriving a key with PBKDF2 from RFC1751 output

Tags: key-generation, pbkdf2

I am building a system that at some point requires a 256 bit key AES key. I used to feed passphrases through PBKDF2 to derive a key, but then I decided to generate random passwords of 12 words selected out of a set of 2048 words which offers me 132 bits of entropy.

Is it safe to pass through PBKDF2 the set of random words encoded or should I pass the equivalent decoded bits?

In other words, if I have the random bits CCAC 2AED 5910 56BE 4F90 FD44 1C53 4766, can I use RASH BUSH MILK LOOK BAD BRIM AVID GAFF BAIT ROT POD LOVE to derive the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter if you pass the random bits or the words mapped to these bits. The strength of the key solely depends on how hard it is too brute-force the input into they KDF (assuming that parameters are kept the same). And assuming that an attacker knows how the input is constructed (i.e. no security by obscurity) the time needed for brute forcing the bits or the mapped words is the same since the space of possible inputs into the KDF has the same size.